# how to return all players in specific football club

Tags: java, class, oop

I am not new to IT or Stack Overflow in general, but am new to java+oop, so please forgive me if the syntax is not correct, 
I'm am trying to level up in java quite quickly and need help with a project I'm working on to improve.

I am trying to recreate the most basic version of football manager, and so far, have a "Club" class and a "Player" class, I have created a few clubs, with their own attributes and values, and now would like to assign players to each club. I have a constructor in each class that will create the individual objects for each club and player, so when I create Marcus Rashford, it looks like this..

```
Player MarcRash = new Player("Marcus", "Rashford", "CF", 10, 20, Mutd);
```

Mutd, being a Club object I created earlier.

10 is his shirt number,
20 is his age //unimportant

Question:
How can I create a method in my `Club` class that will list all players currently assigned to each club?

ie: all the players who currently have the same object as the last parameter in creating them?

```
void listPlayers(Club club) {
 //something here
}
```

thank you for any help.

Comment: `please forgive me if the syntax is not correct` The first thing you should do is run your code through a compiler and make sure the syntax is correct.  In a formal language, syntax determines semantics, and we can't tell what you're trying to say if your syntax is off.

Comment: @markspace the compiler is not the problem so far, my code is working as expected up to this point, I meant my lack of vocabulary to say what I really wanted... after reading back my post once or twice I would hope I can be understood

Comment: A method for your `Club` class would not need a `Club` as an argument.

Comment: you mean `Mutd` is last parameter which is an `Object` right? @Override the `.equals()` method in that class and compare them or if `Mutd` is just a string them compare it, try to update the code so with simple example so that helps more to understand easily

Comment: @SeanDavey That's fine.  I'm just saying you seem like you might be new to software development, and nothing frustrates people trying to help you more than obvious syntax errors.  Just always at least make sure the syntax is correct.

Comment: The true problem is: you dont understand OOP, its ok, but you should read more about it. 
In your class Club, you should have a list of players. 
You can have  a method that return it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution seems "inverted" to me.  Rather than create Players with a fixed club, you should create a player without a club, then assign them to a club.

```
Player marcRash = new Player("Marcus", "Rashford", "CF", 10, 20 );
mutd.add( marcRash );
```

Please also when programming in Java, follow Java's coding guidelines.  Variable names like `marcRush` and `mutd` begin with a lower case letter.

Inside `Club`, you can just list the players that have been added.

```
public class Club {
   private ArrayList<Player> members = new ArrayList<>();

   public void add( Player player ) {
      members.add( player );
   }

   public String listMemebers() {
     if( members.size() == 0 ) return "";
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     for( Player p : members ) {
       sb.append( p.getFirstName() );
       sb.append( " " );
       sb.append( p.getLastName() );
       sb.append( ", " );
    }
    sb.setLength( sb.length()-2 );
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yup, don't assign a 'club' attribute to a Player. A player should be contained in a Club object.

Comment: worked perfectly, thanks so much. You were right, fixing the player to a club was wrong, the player should be assigned to the club object. Thanks for the feedback about variable naming convention also, something I knew, but wasn't using here.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a container for Club classes called League. The League class might then contain a method which takes in a Club object as a parameter and calls a method in the Club class to return all the players in its instance (assuming, for whatever reason, you need this API available in the League class).

The players for a club would be contained in an HashSet in the Club class. So a class variable in the Club class would be:
`HashSet<Player> players;`.

Just a note though. I'd use a HashSet (instead of an ArrayList) to prevent duplicate players in the same club -- which would be impossible in the real world. But in order to use a HashSet, the contained element (Player) would need to implement the methods `equals` and `hashCode`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a List for the Club object like this

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html

`List<Player> players;`
And in your constructor you add each player to the list. 
This type of structure will allow you to have all the Players related to the club

Then you can build your method to print each object on the list

`List<Player> listPlayers(Club club) {
   //Loop through the elements on the list
   // print each Player 
}`